# Insert values into a table from XML (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this XML:

```
<Files>
  <File>
    <Name>pic1</Name> 
    <Description>Pics</Description> 
    <URL>URL1</URL> 
    <TypeText>jpg</TypeText> 
  </File>
  <File>
    <Name>pic2</Name> 
    <Description>Pics</Description> 
    <URL>URL2</URL> 
    <TypeText>jpg</TypeText> 
  </File>
  <File>
    <Name>pic3</Name> 
    <Description>Pics</Description> 
    <URL>URL3</URL> 
    <TypeText>jpg</TypeText> 
  </File>
</Files>
```

And I want to insert them in an SQL Server table. I use this code:

```
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT
    XFiles.value('/Name', 'nvarchar(120)'),
    XFiles.value('/Description', 'nvarchar(300)'),
    XFiles.value('/URL', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    XFiles.value('/TypeText', 'nvarchar(120)')
FROM @FilesXML.nodes('/Files/File')
AS XTbl(XFiles)
```

but it gives me error.

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

I think I'm making a mistake with the `jpath` part. Is it right or wrong?

Thanx in advance

Comment: What is the error? You should provide the error here.

Comment: @Ivica Sorry, Post Updated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alter your select query :

```
SELECT
    XFiles.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(120)') as Name,
    XFiles.value('Description[1]', 'nvarchar(300)'),
    XFiles.value('URL[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    XFiles.value('TypeText[1]', 'nvarchar(120)')
FROM @FilesXML.nodes('/Files/File') as XTbl(XFiles)
```

If you just select `Name`, for example, that XPath query returns a collection of `Name` nodes - even if there's only one child node! - hence the error you're seeing. You have to ensure that the XPath query returns only a single thing, hence adding the `[1]` indexer.